# Не ставится цвет на объект

Tags: c#, unity3d

Когда пишу вот такой код чтобы установить цвет устанавливается всегда белый.

```
        RenderSettings.fogColor = new Color(229, 183, 183, 1);
        Camera.main.backgroundColor = new Color(229, 183, 183, 1);
```

а когда пишу вот так то всё нормально

```
        RenderSettings.fogColor = Color.red;
        Camera.main.backgroundColor = Color.red;
```

Как это исправить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Идем в документацию для Color](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Color.html):

> Representation of RGBA colors.
>
> This structure is used throughout Unity to pass colors around. Each
>   color component is a floating point value with a **range from 0 to 1.**

Если есть какая-то необходимость задавать цвета в диапазоне от 0 до 255, то можно сделать так:

```
RenderSettings.fogColor = new Color(229f/255, 183f/255, 183f/255, 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

В unity используется `new Color(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1);` - серый.

Также допускается `Color color = new Vector4(r, g, b, a);`